# Angular translate with ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, translation

i am working on an application and i want to translate some data in my page. I am using the following angular libraries:
angular-translate and angular-translate-loader-static-files.

i have write these config method:

```
myApp.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: appdifConst.context + '/messages/messages_',
        suffix: '.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

As it seem i get all the json files from /message/messages_*.json when my application starts.
What i want, is to configure this method above in a way that, when my application start to load, only one of the files (for example english which is the predefined) to loaded and when i click on a link (for example fr) the appi to make a post ajax request and brings the messages_fr.json back.
How is that possible?

Comment: beautiful question. I have used it as a reference to use static files loader.. couldn't easily find it elsewhere, and that's a shame because that is probably the common use case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you want is exactly what angular-translate does. It only loads the language that is currently requested (in your case 'en'). What version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug on your side to me, because there's one thing I don't understand..

You say that angular translate downloads ALL the json files.

How does it **KNOW** which translations exist???

My guess is that there is code with `$translationProvider.use(key)` on every language you have.

Perhaps someone thought this is mandatory as part of the setup or something? otherwise it just doesn't make sense that translate will **know** which translations you have and download them.